# How to have a %1 variable in URL in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm using Advanced Installer to create an MSI installer. 
At the very end of the process of the installation, I need to launch a `.bat` file with a variable from Advanced Installer, that is the Windows Path where the MSI is.
The variable is correct, I can see in a dummy `.bat` file. However, in the following situation I get an error, which is not debugged from the AI log.

The `.bat` file has this content:

```
move %1\client c:\xampp\htodcs
```

That is, move the `client` directory in the same path of the MSI to `htdocs` inside `xampp`.
For some reason this fails, I think it may depend on a bad formed URL or maybe backslash is a kind of escape... I repeat, can't debug it from AI and I am not a Windows expert unfortunately.

Comment: That looks like a lower case i to me.  You question says you are using a 1.

Comment: Youi've provided no information on how you're trying to pass the value from your installer to the batch file. You've also said *I get an error*, but failed to tell us what **error** you're getting. Finally, your title says a `%1` variable, but your batch code uses `%i`. A lower case **I** is not the digit **1**

Comment: Sorry, it is %1, as per title. Technically I add in Advanced Installer a custom action pointing to a bat file, with variable [Sourcedir] passed (a property in Advanced installer which represents the path where the MSI is) which I can see in a dummy batch file. Sorry again. Any idea?

Comment: why to downvote this question? I edited it and corrected it!

Comment: What is the value of %1? Does it contain spaces?

Comment: Try: `move "%~1\client" c:\xampp\htodcs`

Comment: Thanks Aacini, this seems to work! Could you please explain what the double quotes and the tilde mean? Thank you again!